# Configure outbound connection over SOAP to 7571 port

Tags: amazon-web-services, soap, amazon-ec2

Right now I have an API which consumes a web service with SOAP over 7571 port.
I wanna migrate that application to AWS EC2 instance but even with all TCP, UDP port for inbound and outbound connections I'm still getting the error message.

```
lumen.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https%3A//example.com%3A7571/ws28t/Services/TranslateWS/TranslateWS.svc%3Fwsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://example.com:7571/ws28t/Services/TranslateWS/TranslateWS.svc?wsdl" ' in /var/www/html/api/app/Lib/Utils.php:89
```

The code on both servers is the same. I have the same commit deployed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using your EC2 public IP while accessing the service? If you don't have ElasticIP, this might change whenever you restart the instance.

Comment: @Nambari I'm using the public IP for now. I also restarted the instance and the problem persist

Comment: If you restarted the instance, there is high possibility that your EC2 public IP might have changed. Make sure you are using valid public IP and are you sure you have wsdl at specified location?